# Offset on UIWindow causes the tab bar to show twice when swiping back

Tags: ios, swift

I am able to move the system keyboard above the tab bar by moving its window up when keyboardWillShowNotification is sent. However when the view controller is embedded in a navigation controller and I'm slowly swiping back, the tab bar appears twice. Also the offset resets to normal if the swipe is cancelled (obviously since kyeboardWillShow event is not triggered). Observing keyboardWillChangeFrame also doesn't apply.

[image]

Here is some sample code to show exactly what I'm doing:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController { }

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 150, height: 150))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.keyboardType = .decimalPad
        view.addSubview(textField)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}

extension SecondViewController {
    private var keyboardOffset: CGFloat {
        return -tabBarHeight
    }

    private var tabBarHeight: CGFloat {
        return tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height ?? 0
    }

    private var keyboardWindowPredicate: (UIWindow) -> Bool {
        return { $0.windowLevel > UIWindow.Level.normal }
    }

    private var keyboardWindow: UIWindow? {
        return UIApplication.shared.windows.last(where: keyboardWindowPredicate)
    }

    @objc private func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue, let keyboardWindow = keyboardWindow {
            keyboardWindow.frame.origin.y = keyboardOffset

        }
    }

    @objc private func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue, let keyboardWindow = keyboardWindow {
            keyboardWindow.frame.origin.y = 0
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}

extension Sequence {
    func last(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Element? {
        return try reversed().first(where: predicate)
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why does this happen and what can I do to prevent this? I know that moving the keyboard is not something usual in iOS, but it was not my decision and I'm trying to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe** the reason is the following:

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan) to `touchesBegan(_:with:)` say:

> UIKit calls this method when a new touch is detected in a view or
>   window. Many UIKit classes override this method and use it to handle
>   the corresponding touch events. The default implementation of this
>   method forwards the message up the responder chain. When creating your
>   own subclasses, call super to forward any events that you do not
>   handle yourself. For example, [super touchesBegan:touches
>   withEvent:event]; If you override this method without calling super (a
>   common use pattern), you must also override the other methods for
>   handling touch events, even if your implementations do nothing.

So the 1st thing I would do is to override, as **requested by the docs**,

> the other methods for handling touch requests, even if your
>   implementations do nothing